# Can we add instances manually in EB data tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have started using elastic beanstalk with tomcat8-java8 application. Elastic beanstalk setup a nice application with RDS data tier. Is it possible to add another instance, which I created manually, in data tier as a redis caching server.
Thanks for any feedbacks.

Comment: ELB is *Elastic Load Balancer*, not Elastic Beanstalk.  This question is not actually about ELB, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing about Elastic Beanstalk that says it cannot communicate with other servers.

An application running under Elastic Beanstalk can access other resources such as S3 buckets, databases, and other servers, etc. as long as the various permission levels allow (VPC, security groups, etc.)

So you can add a redis server manually that your Elastic Beanstalk application can utilize. You just need to ensure that your application can "get to" the redis server.

Comment: I agreed totally with what you said. The only desire ( may be its too much to ask from EB) that if we can map that in the application. The way its shows RDS in data tier.